# Уникальность посетителя через cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Вообщем народ есть такая задача, нужно подсчитать количество уникальных активных посетителей на сайте в данный момент, уникальность определяется через cookie, посетитель считается активным, если он открывал скрипт менее минуты назад. При этом нельзя использовать бд и key-value хранилища, результат оформить в виде PR.

Ладно по поводу уникальность можно генерировать id. Но как вычислить активность и подсчитать кол-во ??

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае я бы добавил еще функцию time() и уже по истечению 60 секунд (как у вас указано), считал бы пользователя не активным (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)